# segmentaion fault runtime error in c doing spiral matrix implementation

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix, runtime-error, spiral

I read a question on hackerearth , it asks us to print the sum of both diagonals of a spiral matrix N*N with N as input. Spiral matrix with a[0][0]=N*N
with 1 at center i.e

```
16  15  14  13

5   4   3   12

6   1   2   11

7   8   9   10
```

I have implemented code for this but gives segmentation or runtime error
when input N >= 10^5

I cant figure out what is happening

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
long long int n,test;
scanf("%lld",&test);
while(test--){
    scanf("%lld",&n);
    long long int p=n*n;
    long long int r1=0,r2=n-1,c1=0,c2=n-1,i,j;
    long long int a[n][n];
    while(p>=1)
    {
        for(i=c1;i<=c2;i++)
        {
            a[r1][i]=p--;
        }
        for(j=r1+1;j<=r2;j++)
        {
            a[j][c2]=p--;
        }
        for(i=c2-1;i>=c1;i--)
        {
            a[r2][i]=p--;
        }
        for(j=r2-1;j>=r1+1;j--)
        {
            a[j][c1]=p--;
        }
        c1++;
        c2--;
        r1++;
        r2--;
    }
    long long int sum=0;
       for ( i = 0, j =0; i< n && j < n; i++, j++) {
              sum = sum + a[i][j];

       }

       for ( i=0,j=n-1 ; i<n && j>=0 ; i++, j--) {
              sum= sum + a[i][j];

       }

           printf("%lld\n",sum%1000000009);


}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: use `malloc` instead of VLA.

Comment: how @BLUEPIXY can u show

Comment: `long long (*a)[n] = malloc(sizeof(long long [n][n]));` instead of.

Answer (score 0):

`long long int a[n][n];` Too large to be secured in the stack if N >= 10^5

replace with `long long (*a)[n] = malloc(sizeof(long long [n][n]));`

---

```
16  15  14  13

5   4   3   12

6   1   2   11

7   8   9   10
```

last element is n * n : (4 * 4 = 16)
pre corner element is last element - (n - 1) : 16 - (4 - 1) = 16 - 3 = 13
pre pre corner element : 13 - 3 = 10
pre pre pre corner element : 10 - 3 = 7
(4 times)

---

A way that doesn't use 2D-array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    long long n;//The length of the side
    long long lastValue;//n*n
    long long sum = 0;

    scanf("%lld", &n);

    sum += (n & 1);//center (1) if odd, Not counting duplicates;

    while(n >= 2){
        lastValue = n * n;
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i){//4 times
            sum += lastValue;
            lastValue -= n - 1;//pre lastValue..
        }
        n -= 2;
    }
    printf("Ans.%lld\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: but it donot gives expected o/p for 10000000 as correct o/p is 679604006 with sum%(10^9 + 9)

Comment: `lastValue -= n - 1;` --> `lastValue -= n - 1;sum %= 1000000009;`